# Python run functions in sequence; if one fails, stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, error-handling

What is the best practice to run functions in sequence?

I have 4 functions, if the previous one failed, do not run the following ones. In each function, I set `global error` and `error = 1` when exception occurs. Then in main, I just use if statement to check the value of `error`. I think there should be a better way to do it.

```
def main():
    engine = conn_engine()
    if error == 0:
        process_sql()
    if error == 0:
        append_new_rows_to_prod()
    if error == 0:
        send_email_log()
```

Comment: The canonical way is to raise an exception within the function. Refrain yourself from using `global`s as they are difficult to debug when there is an issue.

Comment: The "other" canonical way is to return a completion status code.  This is common on UNIX systems, but named exceptions are my preference from long experience with both methods.

Comment: @Prune True. Exit codes lead to defensive programming which makes it harder to read. It has still its uses though, especially in cases when the success or failure of the function can be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way is to raise an exception within the function. For example:

```
def process_sql():
  # Do stuff
  if stuff_failed:
    raise ProcessSQLException("Error while processing SQL")

def append_new_rows_to_prod():
  # Do other stuff
  if other_stuff_failed:
    raise AppendRowsException("Error while appending rows")

def main():
    engine = conn_engine()
    try:
      process_sql()
      append_new_rows_to_prod()
      send_email_log()
    except ProcessSQLException, AppendRowsException as e:
      # Handle exception, or gracefully exit
```