# Ensure either all the function inside a "for" loop runs or none of it does

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am working on a project where I need to extract -> upload -> delete data from a source to a destination.

While the "for" loop is taking each table name and running these (extract/upload/delete) functions one at a time, for each table I want either all of three functions to run and if one or more of them fails then none of the function would run.

For simplicity I have got a dummy loop where I know the first two statement would run but it would fail on the third one. But how do I setup the loop in a way so that either all of them run or if one has an error then none of them will run.

```
table = ['tempA', 'tempB']
extract = 'extract data'
upload = 'upload data'


for x in table:
    print(f"{x} table {extract}")
    print(f"{x} table {upload}")
    print(f"{x} table {delete}")
```

I tried "try" and "except" but that ends up running the first two print statement for both of the table and gives me the error message for the last one.

```
for x in table:
    try:
        print(f"{x} table {extract}")
        print(f"{x} table {upload}")
        print(f"{x} table {delete}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: This isn't possible. You won't be able to know if a function will fail before it is called.

Comment: What you want is a transaction mechanism, that still runs the functions individually, but can unroll the *effects* of earlier ones if any later one fails. If you are using an actual database, this is almost certainly available.

Comment: Like Michael M. has said, this isn't possible in python because python only knows the function will fail at the point it's called. That said, where do your tables live? If it's SQL, rolling back transactions on failure is a standard practice that should achieve what you're looking for? (SQL alchemy is a python library with good support for that type of behaviour)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python run functions in sequence; if one fails, stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057331/python-run-functions-in-sequence-if-one-fails-stop)

Comment: This isn't answerable without details you aren't providing -- we really need to know which _specific_ storage type you're extracting/uploading/deleting data to/from to speak to its transactional capabilities. Without those details this question cannot possibly be answered.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your suggestion. I think that's what I have to do. I am working with bigquery to extract data from one project -> upload it into a different project -> and then delete it from the source project. I am using cloud functions 1st gen but it faces a timeout because it takes longer than 9 minutes to run the function. Which is why I was thinking of rolling back unless the whole extract/upload/delete cycle worked for each table. Can anyone suggest any way that I can do the transaction mechanism to extract>upload>delete data using bigquery?